# eclipse not detecting device which it was detecting a day ago

Tags: android

Eclipse is not detecting my android device (acer ICONIA TAB A500), which it was detecting a day ago. I have tried rebooting my system, updating device driver, changing usb cable, killing and starting adb. Nothing has worked.

Comment: When you run 'adb devices' from the command line, does it show up?

Comment: no it doesn't show any device when I run 'adb device'.

Comment: Windows? Does the tablet show in device manager?

Comment: yes, windows 7 and yes it shows up in device manager

Comment: Do you have developer options checked off in your Iconia Tab's system settings?  And how are you mounting the device: PC Mode, Windows Media Sync, USB Mass Storage, Charge Only, etc.?

Comment: yes, I have developer option checked off and USB debugging checked off as well. I mount the device as charging only.

Comment: Have you tried mounting with other options??  How about doing a factory reset of your device?

Answer (score 2):

**Just for information:**

I was also facing the same issue my Samsung device was not being detected by the `ADB` which was working fine earlier, I changed my cable, restarted Eclipse, restarted my system but nothing worked.
At the end I restarted my Samsung mobile and `ADB` detects it without any problem :)

Comment: Genius! Just restart the test device! Worked with my Nexus 7! Good on ya Irfan